# Is there a way to know in the parent block that you are editing an inner block of that parent?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

The `props.isSelected` of a parent block is true only when you are inside the parent block but not when you are editing inside the innerBlocks of that blocks.

How can I check, from the parent block, if the user is editing an inner block of this parent (no matter how deep)

I'm asking because I want to do some kind of a toggle functionality for the innerBlocks of the parent, to not be visible until you select the parent Block and tried using `props.isSelected` but obviously when you start editing an inner block it immediately disappears because the parent is not selected anymore

Here is a simple code that should demonstrate what I'm talking about

```
registerBlockType('test/parent', {
    name: 'Parent',
    edit: (props) => {
      const template = [['test/child'],['test/child']];
      if (props.isSelected) {
        return <InnerBlocks template={template}/>;
      }
      return <div>Click me to see my inner block</div>;
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return <InnerBlocks.Content />;
    }
};
registerBlockType('test/child', {
    name: 'Child',
    parent: ['test/parent'],
    edit: (props) => {
      return <div>I'm the child I can have some more nested blocks but if you click on me I will be gone because my parent won't want me anymore, I wish somebody could edit me :(</div><InnerBlocks />;
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return <div>I'm the child</div><InnerBlocks.content />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite a lot of research I made my own function to determine if an inner block is selected or not (requires wp-data)

Here is the code

```
registerBlockType('test/parent', {
    name: 'Parent',
    edit: (props) => {
        const template = [['test/child'],['test/child']];
        if (props.isSelected || hasSelectedInnerBlock(props)) {
            return <InnerBlocks template={template}/>;
        }
        return <div>Click me to see my inner block</div>;
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return <InnerBlocks.Content />;
    }
};

function hasSelectedInnerBlock(props) {
    const select = wp.data.select('core/editor');
    const selected = select.getBlockSelectionStart();
    const inner = select.getBlock(props.clientId).innerBlocks;
    for (let i = 0; i < inner.length; i++) {
        if (inner[i].clientId === selected || inner[i].innerBlocks.length && hasSelectedInnerBlock(inner[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. I think the WP should add something similar to support this by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible

> Solution

**Parent Component:**

In the parent component, you can have **flag** in the Component **State** say **childEditted**, and also a handler() say **setChildEditted()**, pass this handler down to child component has a `prop`.

```
class App extends Component {
  State={
    childEditted:false
  }

  setChildEditted = () =>{
      this.SetState({childEditted : true});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          <childComponent onChangeHandler={this.setChildEditted} />
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component:**

child component will use this handler if you have **panel** you can use this handler prop on **onChange()** of the panel, even if there is no panel you can also use it on **div**.

```
 class childComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.props.onChangeHandler}>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way whenever there is a change the parent component state will be updated and the change will be communicated to parent.

Comment: I don't really see how you can pass a handler down to the child, it's not a component directly rendered inside another one where I have control on the props from the parent, it's a block builder, how would you do that in the code I provided?
Thanks for the help